# How can I access information on a public Facebook page with IOT?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I've written an IOT project, but I'm missing the last piece. I need to be able to get the number of likes (in json format) of a public page.

I tried looking into FaceBook developer info, but it seems they make it really hard to understand on purpose.

I tried creating my app. But I can't get my app approved since I don't know / understand how to "create" an app. What kind of files, etc...

I have a server hosting a website with ftp access so no issues hosting any file.
I'm actually looking on comprehensive info on how to create an app I'm pretty good at retro engineering so any example code is actually welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with facebook approval process can be a hassle for sure, these few steps are key to get your app approved.

1. sign in to your developer account and create a new app.
2. submit it to review and ask for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)
    permission, this permission is easy to get approval for and is the one you need.
3. Now usually you need to add a short video showcasing your app "user experience" but since they are giving out this permission to public fields im not sure you need one, try submitting first without it and hope it gets approved. otherwise you need to create a demo, i recommend just screen cast a simple text box input that receives an id and returns a name (just keep it simple and fake it, theres no need to actually use your server or anything except for hosting the file).
4. once you get approved you can use the permission to access public fields on public pages.